# Using node-cmd module while handling Squirrel Events function

Tags: node.js, cmd, electron, node-modules, squirrel.windows

I'm building a desktop app for Windows using `electron-packager` and `electron-squirrel-startup`, I would like to execute some Windows `cmd` commands during the installation of my application. To do so I was planning to use `node-cmd` node module, but I doesn't really work inside the `handleSquirrelEvents` function. An example command like this:

```
function handleSquirrelEvent(application) {  
const squirrelEvent = process.argv[1];
    switch (squirrelEvent) {
       case '--squirrel-install':
       case '--squirrel-updated':
          var cmd=require('node-cmd');
          cmd.run('touch example.created.file');
    }
};
```

Seems to work. A file example.created.file in my_app/node_module/node-cmd/example directory is created.

But any other code does not work. Even if I only change the name of the file to be "touched" nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, example.created.file already exists in this directory and I suspect that you can only use update.exe supported commands in `case '--squirrel-updated'` sections. So this will not work.